# Setting React component initial props when using npm & browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I'm learning [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and have followed the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) guide to setup `npm`, `browserify`, & `babel`.  I'm now able to generate a single `bundle.js` file from my `main.js` file, which I can include in an HTML page to render my react components.  So far so good.

What I can't figure out is how to pass initial values from the `index.html` file into the  components defined in `bundle.js`.  I understand this is a variable scoping problem since `ReactDOM` and the components are not global.

Let me provide an example.  Say in `bundle.js` I have a React component named `Profile`, which generates a small profile widget for a given username.  I don't want to hardcode the username value in `main.js`/`bundle.js` (as it seems many examples do).  I want this to be dynamic and something I can change in the HTML page.  So in my `index.html` page I'd like to do something like the following:

```
<body>
    <div id="profile"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Profile user="bob" />, 
            document.getElementById('profile')
        );
    </script>
</body>
```

This doesn't work, of course, but hopefully demonstrates what I'd like to accomplish.  Does anyone know of a pattern to do something like this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use plain Javascript to create elements, not JSX.

```
<script>
var props = {
  user: "bob",
};

// or you can even serialize data structure of your choice
// var props = <?php echo json_encode($profile); ?>;

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Profile, props),
    document.getElementById('profile')
);
</script>
```

Since Webpack will bundle React/ReactDOM you won't be able to access it globaly. To avoid this, install `expose-loader` for Webpack.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader

```
// index.js may look like this then
require("expose?React!react");
require("expose?ReactDOM!react-dom");
require("expose?Profile!./Profile");
// ./Profile is Profile.js containing component code
```

Comment: I've tried this, but get a JavaScript error that `ReactDOM` is not defined.  It seems my `bundle.js` keeps its variables local. Would it be bad practice to explicitly set `React`, `ReactDOM`, and my components to global variables?  e.g., `window.React = require('react');`, `window.MyComponent = React.createClass({...});`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attribute `user` on the dom element and pass that to component,

here's an example without jsx:

```
const profEl=  document.getElementById('profile')

const Profile = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Profile',
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement('div', {
          className: "prof"
        },
       profEl.attributes.user.value , ' is the name'
      )
    );
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Profile, null),
  profEl
);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/u31hda0j/5/)